# Coverage phpunit on Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, code-coverage

I excute PhPUnit, The coverage report can not generate,
Laravel ver: 5.2
Php ver: 7.3.11.
Log output is:

> PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors. .
>
> Time: 1.51 seconds, Memory: 22.00MB
>
> OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
>
> Generating code coverage report in HTML format ...count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

I don't know what wrong here?
Here is my test source:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class TravelControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
         $response = $this->json('GET', '/v1/abc', ['id' => 'Sally']);
         $response->assertSessionHas('temporary_id', $value = 'Sally');
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957945/php-7-2-count-error

Comment: What's the reason to use PHPUnit 4 and on PHP 7.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade the PHPUnit and PhpCodeCoverage packages would be the solution. You're packages are very outdated! It's a bug in older versions.

Here are some discussions about this topic:

https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/4703

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/551

Comment: Thanks for your help. So sory but I can't update PHPUnit  ver. I try: "composer install" and log is:
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating phpunit/phpunit (4.8.36 => 7.0.0): Loading from cache. But when I excute test, log output is sample fist time: PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Comment: So post your `composer.json` file in your question.

Comment: Delete the `composer.lock` file and execute `composer update --no-cache`.

Comment: What? I can‘t understand you.